# How to upload an app onto a device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, device

I am running Android Studio on Linux. I would like to upload my app onto my Galaxy Nexus. Is there a simple way of doing that from the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that debug is enabled on your phone, and that the appropriate usb driver is installed.  Then it should appear in the run config in Android Studio.

Check out the following guide for more information: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: This only runs the app over the phone. Does not actually install it. How do I install the app on the phone?

Comment: Either manually use the "adb install "your-app.apk" command, but if you're using gradle, I think there's an install goal you can call (I think it was gradle installDebug)

Comment: You may need to use the -r option to modify adb install if the app has been previously run using the debugger. ($ adb install -r your-app.apk)

Answer (score 0):

Just click the `play` green icon, or <kbd>Shift + F10</kbd> will compile you android app and ask you to run it on a real device or in the Android Virtual Device emulator!

Please remember to attach your device to your computer before.

Comment: I plugged my device using a USB cable. It is visible as a camera device, but I can't choose it to run in Android Studio (there is no device there).